# How to convert a video in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv, converters

Program to convert a video file into a NumPy array and vice-versa. I had searched for many search engines but was unable to find the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are multiple libraries people use for this (i.e. `PyAV`, `decord`, `opencv`); I personally use Python OpenCV for this a lot (mostly with PyTorch, but it's a similar principle), so I'll speak about my experience there. You can use `cv2.VideoCapture` to load a video file into a `numpy` array; in theory, you can also use `cv2.VideoWriter` to write it back, but in practice, I've had a hard time getting that to work in my own projects.

#### Video to Numpy Array

tl;dr: Create a `cv2.VideoCapture` wrapper; iteratively load images (i.e. frames) from the video.

```
frames = []

path = "/path/to/my/video/file.mp4"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
ret = True
while ret:
    ret, img = cap.read() # read one frame from the 'capture' object; img is (H, W, C)
    if ret:
        frames.append(img)
video = np.stack(frames, axis=0) # dimensions (T, H, W, C)
```

Do note that the images will be returned in BGR channel format rather than the more common RGB; if you need to convert it to the RGB colorspace, `img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)` will be sufficient.

### Numpy Array to Video

In theory, the examples I've seen for using `cv2.VideoWriter` go something like

```
# let `video` be an array with dimensionality (T, H, W, C)
num_frames, height, width, _ = video.shape

filename = "/path/where/video/will/be/saved.mp4"
codec_id = "mp4v" # ID for a video codec.
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*codec_id)
out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, fourcc=fourcc, fps=20, frameSize=(width, height))

for frame in np.split(video, num_frames, axis=0):
    out.write(frame)
```

You can also save the frames to temporary images (there exist many `np.ndarray` -> image pipelines; I personally use Pillow), then use `ffmpeg` (a command-line utility) to encode the frames into a video file. This takes up significantly more space though, and I use this method when I need to inspect the individual frames of my video array (in that case, I use `ffmpeg`, but that's a different conversation).

And on another note -- you may want to change the `codec_id` variable depending on how you want to encode the video (if this means nothing to you, don't worry -- it probably won't matter for your application); this is simply a four-byte code used to identify the video codec used to generate the video (see [this page](https://www.fourcc.org/codecs.php); availability may vary by platform(. H.264 is the most common one in use today AFAIK, which is given by code "H264" or "X264", but I've had trouble getting this to work with OpenCV ([more details here](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/81)); however, the `array -> images -> video file` approach works seamlessly with `ffmpeg` from the command line.

Comment: Thank you, very much please let me know if I could help you in future. I am really thankful to you @tchaizz

Comment: Hello, I have a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410822/pyav-how-to-create-audioframes-for-aiortc